# Filter for daily time range with dynamic date

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

How can i filter for certain time ranges which are not using a fixed date ?
e.g.

22:00 yesterday - 06:00 today
06:00 today - 14:00 today
14:00 today - 22:00 today

is there something like a universal date-format which is not fixing the date?

Comment: mark the below as an answer or post your solution to help others. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I dont think your question is very clear but are you looking for relative time queries?
Like now-1d etc, if so check Elastic date math [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math).